# Convert a Windows Phone 8.1 project into a Portable Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I haven't been able to find any information on this issue:
I have a C++ Windows Phone 8.1 library project, I would like to convert it into a portable library without having to recreate the project and set all parameters.

I guess it should be possible to do it by editing the vcxproj file, but I don't know how to modify it to make it work.

I meet several issues:

1. What is the equivalent of Portable Library (C#) for C++?
2. How to change an existing Windows Phone 8.1 C++ project into this equivalent?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Windows Phone 8.x doesn't support sharing of binaries with Windows desktop because the import libraries are different between the two (eg, desktop apps link against kernel32.dll but that DLL doesn't exist on Windows Phone). You could share between Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1 though (provided you only used features available in 8.0).

In theory you might be able to make a static lib that was shared if it didn't depend on any Windows APIs, but it's not really supported. You could try creating a new Static Library project and diffing it against your current project to see what settings have changed.

This changes in Windows 10, where shared binaries are fully supported (obviously you still need ARM vs x86 vs x64 builds depending on CPU architecture).

Comment: This library is quite independant, it does not require system libraries (it has its own external libraries), therefore it is possible to compile it for desktop, and at least for WinRT.
However I don't need it right now, it was just to have a cleaner base for future evolutions, but as it is not developped by me, but by a third party I will let it for later (W10) when my app will be finished.
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Maximize code reuse between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681693%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) C++ is not supported as PCL language as this is a .net framework technology.

> Note that Portable Class Libraries are a .NET Framework concept and don’t support C++

I also looked into Visual Studio to confirm that and couldn't find a template.

Comment: Are you looking for a static library or a DLL or maybe a WinRT library? And portable across which platforms?

Comment: Thanks for this information. However I may not require exactly the "Portable" project type, but some library that can be shared among WP8.1 (not silverlight, but could be as a bonus), Win8 (and potentially Win32 as a bonus as well :) )

By the way, I don't exactly know the difference between static library (.Lib?) and DLL